# Adding new columns for data using Mapreduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Is it possible to append columns in mapreduce while processing data? 
Example:

I have input dataset with 3 columns[EMPID,EMPNAME,EMP_DEPT] and I want to process these data using mapreduce. In the reduce phase is it possible to add new columns say TIMESTAMP(system timestamp when record get processed). Output of the reducer should be EMPID,EMPNAME,EMP_DEPT,TIMESTAMP

Input Data:

```
EMPID EMPNAME EMP_DEPT
1       David   HR
2       Sam     IT
```

Output Data:

```
EMPID EMPNAME EMP_DEPT Timestamp
1       David   HR      XX:XX:XX:XX
2       Sam     IT      XX:XX:XX:XX
```

Comment: please be more specific

Comment: @vefthym I have updated the question. Please have a look

Comment: better, but still need some details. What kind of processing do you perform? What is the type of input of the reducer? Do you have any code that we can see and correct? Do you use Hive?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the purpose of your MapReduce is just to add the timestamp "column" (regarding your input and output example there is no other modification/transformation/processing of the EMPID, EMPNAME and EMP_DEPT fields). If that is the case, the only thing you have to do is to add to the read lines ("rows") the timestamping in the mapper; then let the reducer joins all the new "rows". Workflow:

```
Each input file is splited into many chunks:
(input file) --> spliter --> split1, split2, ..., splitN

Each split content is:
split1 = {"1 David HR", "2 Sam IT"}
split2 = {...}

Splits are assigned to mappers (one per split), which output (key,value) pairs; in this case, it is enough with a common key for all the pairs:
(offset, "1 David HR") --> mapper1 --> ("key", "1 David HR 2015-06-13 12:23:45.242")
(offset, "2 Sam IT") --> mapper1 --> ("key", "2 Sam IT 2015-06-13 12:23:45.243")
...
"..." --> mapper2 --> ...
...

The reducer receives an array, for each different key, with all the pairs outputted by the mappers that have such a key:
("key", ["1 David HR 2015-06-13 12:23:45.242", "2 Sam IT 2015-06-13 12:23:45.243"]) --> reducer --> (output file)
```

If your aim is to finally process the original data in some way, do it at the mapper, in addition to the timestamping.